# Combine arrays and shuffling two arrays in order

Tags: python, random

The title is a little tricky, but this is what I want to mean:
I have 2 arrays

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
B = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

I want to merge and shuffle them but keeping their orders, something like this:

```
C = [1, 2, 'a', 3, 'b', 'c', 4, 'd', 'e', 5]
```

As you can see, they are randomly merged, but they kept their individual order. How could I do that?

Note that the merge does not have to be in any certain distribution while it is ordered as I asked.

Comment: When you say "random", you have to define some distribution. Should a merge like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` be allowed? With what probability?

Comment: A quick way that gives "nice looking" results that avoid clumping/avalanche-like behavior is probably to evenly distribute the indices of the smaller array, and then offset the indices by some gaussian "noise" distribution.

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq yes, it will be allowed. But it doesn't need a certain probability.

Comment: And what does this have to do with NumPy?

Comment: @mkrieger1 the problem that I face is to plot 2 differents arrays shuffled both with a relation in time. Therefore, I can not simply shuffle them, it has to be like my problem describe. And it has to do with NumPy bc my arrays are np.array(), so maybe there was a function in NumPy that allows what my problem require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import random

A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
B = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
output = []

while A and B:
    # choosing randomly from which list to pick the first element
    if bool(random.getrandbits(1)):
        output.append(A.pop(0))
    else:
        output.append(B.pop(0))
output += A + B # since the while loop stops when the first list is empty, we should add the rest of the elements to the end of the output
print(output)
```

Comment: This method appears to be *very* susceptible to clumping. For example, on trial run #4, this generated the output `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']`. I won't downvote (yet) since the OP hasn't defined any requirements properly, but I don't think the results are very nice looking.

Comment: @Mateen thats randomness for you: drawing 100 numbers in the range 0..99 can give you all of them in exact order - its just quite unlikely

Comment: @MateenUlhaq you are very lucky ;) It should be completely random process.

Comment: Hmmm... but this was trial run #5: `['a', 'b', 'c', 1, 'd', 'e', 2, 3, 4, 5]`. It's a random process but that doesn't mean the distribution is desired.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq the OP didn't mention anything on the distribution of the values.

Comment: Right, but from that perspective, generating `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` [999999](https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25) times and `[1, 2, 'a', 3, 'b', 'c', 4, 'd', 'e', 5]` the other 1 time is a valid probability distribution. As I said, I'm not downvoting but I don't think the results are very useful, at least not for small (or perhaps even large) `len(A)` and `len(B)`.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq usefulness is a matter of perspective. I am just trying to help the asker and that's what was asked.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Thank you all. The merge does not have to be in a certain distribution while it is ordered as i asked.